# Get raw data Skin Conductance Data/ Galvanic Skin Responce (GSR) and Heart Rate Variablitiy(HRV) from microsoft band

Tags: sdk, skin, microsoft-band

Is it possible to get the raw Skin Conductance/ Galvanic Skin Responce and the Heart Rate Variability from the microsoft band?
What software is needed, if any?

I am interested because of research purposes.

Ps. I don't own a microsoft band yet, if this is possible I would be very interested to buy one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the Microsoft Band can provide GSR & HR. Check the SDK to find all the possibilities https://developer.microsoftband.com/bandSDK

Comment: Can you complete your question or check the answer?